# Custom Hook - return state and set state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to use a custom hook similarly as described here:
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

This is my custom hook:

```
export const useProcesses = (id: string, token: string, enqueueSnackbar: NotificationFunction) => {
    const [processes, setProcesses] = useState<ProcessDTO[]>([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProcesses = async () => {
            setIsError(false);
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                if (id !== undefined) {
                    const response = await new HttpService()
                        .withToken(token)
                        .get(createProcessesPathForIdEndpoint(id), enqueueSnackbar);

                    const data = response.data.data;
                    setProcesses(data);
                    return data;
                }
            } catch {
                setIsError(true);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        };

        fetchProcesses();
    }, [enqueueSnackbar, id, token]);
    return [{ Processes, isLoading, isError }, setProcesses];
    };
```

I am accessing the hook as:

```
    const [{ processes, isLoading, isError }, setProcesses] = useProcesses(
    id,
    token,
    enqueueSnackbar,
);
```

The typescript error received is:

```
Property 'Processes' does not exist on type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<ProcessDTO[]>> | { Processes: ProcessDTO[]; isLoading: boolean; isError: boolean; }'.  TS2339
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You return `Processes` from hook: `return [{ Processes, isLoading, isError }, setProcesses];`
and try to get `quotationProcesses`: `const [{ quotationProcesses, isLoading, isError }, setQuotationProcesses] = `.
To rename field in object destruction you should use `[{ Processes: quotationProcesses, isLoading, isError }, setQuotationProcesses]`

Comment: Oh nice spot, but this was only bad formating from my side for Stack Overflow. In my code Processes=quotationProcesses :)
Will edit my Source Code

Comment: Then the issue is that return result is inferred as array not a tuple. You should either add explicit return type to the function or add `as const`: `return [{ Processes, isLoading, isError }, setProcesses] as const`. This will narrow the type to tuple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like Typescript isn't inferring the return type in the way that you want it. It fails for simple examples too, like this one:

```
const thingy = () => {
    return ['abc', 9, 'abcd']
}
const [a, b, c] = thingy() // a, b, and c are all of type 'string|number'
```

We need to to give Typescript a little help, so we explicitly declare the return type, which will allow the variables `a b c` to have the correct types:

```
const thingy = (): [string, number, string] => {
    ...
```

For your code, you'll want something like this:

```
type UseProcessesResult = [
    {
        processes: ProcessDTO[],
        isLoading: boolean,
        isError: boolean,
    },
    Dispatch<SetStateAction<ProcessDTO[]>>,
]
export const useProcesses = (id: string, token: string, enqueueSnackbar: NotificationFunction): UseProcessesResult {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.
Out of interest: Is this to be classified as a Typescript Bug or is it just in the nature of TS that not all types can be inferred and you have to manually set them sometimes?