# Lifespan of the React state values created inside a hook / component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Reference: [Custom Hook - return state and set state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813282/custom-hook-return-state-and-set-state) :

```
export const useProcesses = (id: string, token: string, enqueueSnackbar: NotificationFunction) => {
    const [processes, setProcesses] = useState<ProcessDTO[]>([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProcesses = async () => {
            setIsError(false);
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                if (id !== undefined) {
                    const response = await new HttpService()
                        .withToken(token)
                        .get(createProcessesPathForIdEndpoint(id), enqueueSnackbar);

                    const data = response.data.data;
                    setProcesses(data);
                    return data;
                }
            } catch {
                setIsError(true);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        };

        fetchProcesses();
    }, [enqueueSnackbar, id, token]);
    return [{ Processes, isLoading, isError }, setProcesses];
    };
```

- I have a react hook, inside it creates some state using useState.
- At the end, it returns the states.

1. Is the hook unmounted when it returns ?  When does the hook unmount ?
2. For how long are the states `processes, isLoading, isError` available after the hook returns ?

If, instead of a hook, I have a functional component which I render on the main screen, and inside this component, I have created a state (eg stateA). What is the lifespan of stateA ?  As long as the the browser remains on the main screen ?

For a component, I can see it on the screen and I can visualise it more easily.  But for a hook which fetches values, I cannot see it, so I find it difficult to see how long the states lives.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

React hooks: it’s just like a normal function. They won't store anything. You should be do the storing when hook return your values.

As far as i know, If you storing in a component. They are only stored in memory(ex. your states) while the page is loaded So when you route from a page or refresh that you lose your state. To prevent that there is [React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start), you can access your parameters in whole of your app.

Comment: But the code I've quoted says that it's possible to create a state inside the hook and then return it.  That's why I needed to ask the questions for clarification.